# The multi-part identifier "Transaction_tbl.locid" could not be bound while using join in case statement in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query like this:

```
select  sum(status_receved) as Receved, sum(status_parked) as Parked,
 sum(status_requested) as Requested,sum(status_requestedinprocess) as Requestinprocess,
 sum(status_deliverd) as Deliverd
  from (select case when (status = 0 ) then 1 else 0 end as status_receved,
case when (status = 2) then 1 else 0 end as status_parked, 
case when (status = 3) then 1 else 0 end as status_requested,
case when(status=4) then 1 else 0 end as status_requestedinprocess,
case when(Status=5) then 1 else 0 end status_deliverd
from transaction_tbl where locid in(5) and status in (0,2,3,4))   a
```

this query is working fine. i am getting result like this:

```
Receved     Parked      Requested   Requestinprocess Deliverd
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------- -----------
1           37          0           3                0
```

I also have a location_master table, and I want to show the corresponding location name before. My `locid=5` is **`Bur dubai`**. I tried to write a query something like this:

```
    SELECT  LocName ,
        SUM(status_receved) AS Receved ,
        SUM(status_parked) AS Parked ,
        SUM(status_requested) AS Requested ,
        SUM(status_requestedinprocess) AS Requestinprocess ,
        SUM(status_deliverd) AS Deliverd
FROM    ( SELECT    l.LocName ,
                    CASE WHEN ( status = 0 ) THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
                    END AS status_receved ,
                    CASE WHEN ( status = 2 ) THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
                    END AS status_parked ,
                    CASE WHEN ( status = 3 ) THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
                    END AS status_requested ,
                    CASE WHEN ( status = 4 ) THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
                    END AS status_requestedinprocess ,
                    CASE WHEN ( Status = 5 ) THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
                    END status_deliverd
          FROM      transaction_tbl t
                    INNER JOIN Location_tbl l ON l.Locid = t.locid
          WHERE     t.Locid IN ( 5 )
                    AND status IN ( 0, 2, 3, 4 ) 
        ) a;
```

But I am getting this error:Column 'a.LocName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The result I would like to get is this:

```
Location  Receved     Parked      Requested   Requestinprocess Deliverd
 ---     ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------- -----------
Burdubai    1           37          0           3                0
```

Comment: In both Select and Where clause, table name not specified for column "Status". You should use "tablename.Status" and SUM(a.status_receved)

Comment: yes you should join INNER JOIN Location_tbl l after sum.create one more select on top of "sum select" then join it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that SQL Server was installed with case-sensitive option. You can check: execute `sp_server_info` and look at `18  COLLATION_SEQ` on `sort_order`.
On my server it is set to `nocase_iso` that means if you already have Column `A` column in a table you can not add `a` column: they are the same if `sort_order` is set to `nocase_iso`.

If so then just change `on l.Locid=t.locid` to proper case `on l.Locid=t.Locid`

Also in your query you are selecting `l.LocName` from subquery that doesn't return `LocName` column. Rewrite as

```
    SELECT  LocName ,
            SUM(status_receved) AS Receved ,
            SUM(status_parked) AS Parked ,
            SUM(status_requested) AS Requested ,
            SUM(status_requestedinprocess) AS Requestinprocess ,
            SUM(status_deliverd) AS Deliverd
    FROM    ( SELECT    l.LocName ,
                        CASE WHEN ( status = 0 ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END AS status_receved ,
                        CASE WHEN ( status = 2 ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END AS status_parked ,
                        CASE WHEN ( status = 3 ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END AS status_requested ,
                        CASE WHEN ( status = 4 ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END AS status_requestedinprocess ,
                        CASE WHEN ( Status = 5 ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END status_deliverd
              FROM      transaction_tbl t
                        INNER JOIN Location_tbl l ON l.Locid = t.locid
              WHERE     t.Locid IN ( 5 )
                        AND status IN ( 0, 2, 3, 4 )
            ) a
      GROUP BY LocName;
```

Comment: mine showing:18 COLLATION_SEQ charset=iso_1 sort_order=nocase_iso charset_num=1 sort_order_num=52

Comment: so now i have to change anything in my query

Comment: @user3252014, Also in your query you are selecting `l.LocName` from subquery that douesn't return LocName column.

Comment: instead of that what i have to write?

Comment: getting error like this:Column 'a.LocName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Then you had pasted wrong test statement. It couldn't write that error. There are no groupings. It is clear that you are testing on different statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69984/discussion-between-user3252014-and-giorgi-nakeuri).

Comment: @user3252014, there is a problem loading chat. You can update your question and paste exact that statement with groups...

Comment: sir i update my question.did u see my expected out put?

Comment: @user3252014, was my mistake sorry. you should add group by LocName in the end of the statement. check updated answer